# compact metric space where metric is surjective on $[0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following problem and I was wondering if my argument below is okay:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space with the property that for every $t \in (0,1)$, there exist points $x_t,y_t$ in $X$ such that $d(x_t,y_t)=t$. Prove that there exist points $x,y$ in $X$ such that $d(x,y)=1$.

My argument: $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. By hypothesis, $[0,1) \subset d[X \times X]$ However, $d[X \times X] \not \subset [0,1)$ (otherwise, $d[X \times X] = [0,1)$, which implies that $[0,1)$ is compact, which is not true). Since $d[X \times X]$ MUST be compact, $1$ $\in$ $d[X \times X]$, which is what we want.

It's the last statement I'm not sure about how to explicitly justify (or even if I can using this argument), so any help would be appreciated.

I'd also be interested in seeing how an alternate argument might proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$X$ compact $\implies$ $X^2$ compact $\implies$ $d[X^2]$ compact $\implies$ $1\in d[X^2]$ since it's closed.

---

Alternatively, there is a sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\to1$. WLOG $x_n\to x$ because of compactness and similarly WLOG $y_n\to y$. Then $d(x,y)=1$ from the continuity of the metric.